# Wait for a webclient remote flux with awaitility

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am testing a `webclient` that returns a flux and I need to wait for it to initialise properly. Like this

I setup a flux as null

```
private Flux<Event> events = null;
```

Then call a webclient to get the Flux from a remote URL

```
Flux<String> events = getFlux(guid);
```

The webclient is

```
WebClient client; // already setup with headers and URL

public Flux<String> getFlux(String guid) {

    return client.get()
        .uri(Props.getBaseEndpoint() + "?id=" + guid)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(status -> status.value() == 401,clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
        .bodyToFlux(String.class)
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(Props.getTimeout()));
}
```

The `getFlux` method appears to return before the Flux is completely initialised. So I want to wait a couple of seconds for it:

```
Awaitility.await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(isFluxInitialised());
```

where something like:

```
public Callable<Boolean> isFluxInitialised() {
    return new Callable<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            if (events != null)
                return true;
            
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Waiting for the `Flux` to be not null still causes a race condition in the test. I can't figure out what to wait for so that the `getFlux` has returned an initialised `Flux` that can then be subscribed to. The test continues with a subscription to the flux as below but finishes before the test data that's sent to the remote endpoint can arrive in the subscription.

```
events.subscribe(e -> Logs.Info("event: " + e));
```

Here's the intellisense

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the logic of the `isFluxInitialised` but looking at the description you could be confused by [Assembly vs Subscription time](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription). Also, please note that `subscribe` is not synchronous operation and your program could exit before results are available.

I would suggest to start with unit test using `StepVerifier` to make sure your flow is correct.

```
StepVerifier.create(getFlux(...))
    .expectNextCount(count)
    .verifyComplete();
```

If you need to wait until `Flux` is complete in your logic you can use common pattern using `CountDownLatch`. The same can be achieved with `Awaitility` if you like.

```
CountDownLatch completionLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);


getFlux(...)
   .doOnComplete(completionLatch::countDown)
   .doOnNext(e -> Logs.Info("event: " + e))
   .subscribe();


completionLatch.await();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to introduce blocking operator `blockFirst()` into the flow. Still not sure about the use case but technically you are trying to wait for the first element from the `Flux`. The same could be achieved without blocking

```
AtomicBoolean elementAvailable = new AtomicBoolean();

getFlux()
        .doOnNext(rec -> elementAvailable.set(true))
        .subscribe();

Awaitility.await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(elementAvailable::get);
```

Comment: use case is testing a remote flux that takes time to complete `assembly` so by the time the remote flux is setup the test case has already finished unless you `await`

Comment: Oh. Then consider using ‘StepVerifier’ https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_testing_a_scenario_with_stepverifier

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alex answer about assembly v subscription time. That's the problem. I actually got the `awaitility` to work properly by moving it off waiting for "assembly" time (which I couldn't get to work) and instead to wait for the 1st subscription, by using `blockFirst()` as below:

```
Awaitility.await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(isFluxInitialised());
```

and

```
public Callable<Boolean> isFluxInitialised() {
    return new Callable<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            if (events.blockFirst() != null)
                return true;
            
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Please note that blockFirst is a blocking operation and is used to transform reactive to non-reactive “world”. You will loose all advantages of reactive flow. I’m still not sure what do you want to achieve here but technically you are waiting for the first “onNext’ event. Just initialize some variable in doOnNext and wait for it

Comment: It's ok to wait until the first response because it's about [awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. You are introducing blocking call that should be avoided if possible in reactive. If you want to block - just replace `subscribe` with `blockLast`.